Implications of the AGPL 3.0 License for integrated methods
We are developing a toolkit primarily as a QGIS Plugin (basically a collection of Python code and related scripts that can be run within QGIS). It is a collection of tools and algorithms revolving around forest stand delineation and processing.
In this collection, we have a method/an algorithm that a partner contributed. It was originally developed in MATLAB (let's call it algorithm X1), but was adopted to Python/QGIS for this toolkit (let's call the adopted algorithm X2).
We are also proactively assuming a case, where another person might have developed an algorithm Y1 that he wants to contribute to our toolkit project (in an almost unchanged or only slightly adjusted version algorithm Y2).
The whole project now wants to go Open Source and we are leaning towards a strong copyleft license (AGPL 3.0). By publishing our code containing this algorithm X2 we are putting it as well under AGPL 3.0 license. Any contribution to the project will implicitly, as well, be put under the license.
My question(s):

Does the already integrated contribution of X2 imply, that the algorithm X1 it originates from now also is bound by the AGPL 3.0 License and hence any change to X1 (made independently from X2) has to be made Open Source (satisfying the copyleft requirement)?
Does an anticipated contribution of Y2 (originating from an almost identical source Y1) imply that Y1 is from now on also bound by AGPL 3.0 and any change to Y1 has to be made public / Open Source?

If yes, are there copyleft licenses that avoid this issue? (LGPL / MPL and GPL all seem to make sure, changes are "copylefted", despite the ability to privately integrate the whole thing into a proprietary system). Or is the only option to avoid this using a permissive license: Public Domain, MIT, or the likes

Is the contributor of Y1 (or Y2) contributing only an algorithm, or a modified version of your program containing an implementation thereof?

@MadHatter: an independent algorithm that is not in any way building upon our program (although by integrating it and creating a version X2/Y2 it may use components of the existing program, but that can be treated as a separate case. My interest is first and foremost about the implications for the original code X1/Y1)


The whole project now wants to go Open Source and we are leaning towards a strong copyleft license (AGPL 3.0).

This suggests to me that the project maintainers are considering to change the license of the project. Be aware that changing the license can only be done

if you have explicit, written permission from all contributors (past and present) to the project that you can distribute their contribution under the new license terms, or
if the current license allows a change of the licensing terms (to the selected license)

If neither of those conditions is true, you cannot legally change the license of your project.



Does the already integrated contribution of X2 imply, that the algorithm X1 it originates from now also is bound by the AGPL 3.0 License and hence any change to X1 (made independently from X2) has to be made Open Source (satisfying the copyleft requirement)?
Does an anticipated contribution of Y2 (originating from an almost identical source Y1) imply that Y1 is from now on also bound by AGPL 3.0 and any change to Y1 has to be made public / Open Source?


No, distributing an implementation of an algorithm under a strong copyleft license does not mean that another implementation of the same algorithm has to be made open-source.
However, the person creating the X2 or Y2 implementations must have the right to release those implementations under the AGPL license.
The original authors of the X and Y algorithms automatically have that right for their respective algorithms, but someone who just translates the X1 implementation from Matlab to Python (and creating X2 in that way) only has that right if the copyright license on the Matlab code permits it. And similar for how Y2 is derived from Y1.
The bottom line with third-party code is that you can only deal with it in ways that are permitted by the original author.

Great, the first sentence of your second paragraph tells me what I needed to know, Thank you! Also thank you for further elaborating and the hint to get written permission from all original authors. Currently we have no license at all, but there are only few contributors so far and most of them acted within their employment as university staff, so getting those permissions shouldn't be a problem.

@Honeybear: If they were employed by the university, and the work was within the scope of their employment, then depending on jurisdiction, the copyright may be owned by the university and not by the individuals. If the university provides legal aid or has in-house counsel, you may want to consult them for specific advice.
